# Unknown freehub, trying to source

Tags: wheels, hub, freewheel

I have a neighbours daughters bike to fix at the moment. The freehub is totally seized. I've removed the freehub from the hub itself, but can't identify it nor have I see any like it. It doesn't have a separate locking screw and screws into the hub itself.

It looks similar to a DMR, Halo, or Sun freehub but it's only a cheap hub. The one that looks closest so far is the DMR. Yet the DMR has what looks like an aluminium bit at the end of the thread:

http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=7685

Pictures of the freehub are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue5S0.jpg

[image][image]

Comment: you might be out of luck with these ones. Probably would be easier to replace the whole rear hub and re-lace the wheel.

Comment: What did the freehub cost from Silverfish? I've been on there looking for the same thing but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The freehub turned out to be a Formula freehub. I managed to source it from Silverfish UK.